# Do you loose liability protection if doing work for your LLC on your personal computer?

Tags: liability, limited-liability-company

Do you have potential of loosing liability protection if doing work for your LLC on your personal computer (ie. a computer purchased with personal funds and not accounted for as being owned by the LLC)? For example, what if had customer data like purchase orders stored in a folder on you personal computer? Does this count [as](https://www.nolo.com/legal-encyclopedia/limited-liability-protection-llcs-a-50-state-guide.html)

> treating the LLC as an extension of their personal affairs, rather than as a separate legal entity

since you are commingling the usage of your personal property?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No more than using your own phone, eyeglasses or underwear while working for the LLC. These are all tools of trade than one wold expect employees of the LLC to bring to their job (especially underwear).

There is potentially a problem if assets of the LLC are alienated for personal use rather than the other way around. However, that would be subject to a reasonableness test - using your work computer to book a personal holiday is eminently reasonable.

Where there is a real liability issue is if the use of that personal asset caused damage to third parties e.g. if the personal computer was hacked and damage resulted. This would allow a potential plaintiff to bypass the LLC and sue the owner directly (or, more likely, as well).